# major package upgrades - can we avoid dataloss without needing to export and manually re-import the data between reinstalls?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

Can you publish and push a 'major' update to a managed package (appexchange) without causing immediate dataloss of pre-update same package packaged records?

Update 2020-04-25T10:53:49-0700:  The accepted answer taught me that I had made a bad assumption about needing to reinstall for major upgrades. Thanks for showing me that Uninstall/reinstall is unnecessary during major upgrades.

Comment: Are you asking if installing orgs will suffer package data loss upon installing a major upgrade to the application? If so, the answer is no. Though you also mentioned reinstalls in your question header which would imply an uninstall first, which could be a different story... having trouble piecing together what you are really asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Im asking if an installing org would suffer data loss after receiving a major upgrade to a managed package. I thought that no new components are allowed in patches, thus new components require major upgrade, and i assumed major upgrade required reinstall. Bad assumption?

Comment: Gotcha! Just posted an answer. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade a major version of an app, users do not need to uninstall/reinstall - they just need to follow the link to the upgraded package version (or go through standard AppExchange install process, assuming the version has been published). Upon doing this, SF will detect they have an earlier version of the package and will provide an Upgrade option instead of Install.

No data is lost when going through the upgrade process - it's pretty seamless. Bear in mind though that if your upgrade contains new components that need to be populated in order for the app to function properly, you may want to look into writing an install handler that programmatically populates these components upon the update.

You can see more info about install handlers here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm